# Create a New Github Repository from Existing Github Repository

Tags: git, github

I have a situation where I needed to create a new repository from the existing repository on Github (with different name) but I want to import the log/history as well from the old repository.

Is there a way to do this?

The use-case here is to separate a component from the existing repository by duplicating the repository and prune until we achieved the goal.

Comment: `git clone` the existing repo and then push to your newly created repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what that "fork" button (in the upper right of the screen when viewing a repository on GitHub) does.  It will create a copy of the repository (which includes the entire history) with another name.

You can also:

- `git clone` the existing repository to your local filesystem
- Create a new empty repository on GitHub
- Optionally add a new remote to your local repository pointing at the new GitHub repository (`git remote add ...`)
- `git push` your local repository to the new GitHub repository

Comment: I thought Fork would put it under my name? github.com/username/forkname? I want it to be under the same org.

Comment: If you are a member of the organization you can choose to make the fork belong to the org rather than to your user account.  When you click the "fork" button you will be presented with a dialog where you can select a target for the new repository.